# Jupyter | How to use matplotlib to plot multiple lines on only one plot in a for loop and keeping the previous lines?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot 5 lines on a plot in a for-loop. In every iteration, the values of x and y appended to an np.array and then plotted on a figure.
The problem that I have is that I want all the lines on one plot as their x values are always the same but the values of y will change.

Here is how I do it:

```
for i in range (0,5):
    for epoch in range(0, num_epochs):
        x = np.append(x,epoch)
        y = np.append(y,accuracy)
        z = np.append(z, running_loss/j)

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
    fig.suptitle('Model Evlauation')
    axs[0].plot(x, y)
    axs[1].plot(x, z)
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Number of epochs')
    axs[1].set_xlabel('Number of epochs')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('Accuracy')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('Loss')
    fig.tight_layout(pad=2)
    plt.show()
```

in this way, I get 5 different figures and each one includes only one line:
[image]

while I want something like the following figure:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the subplots in the for loop, it is set again every time. So instead you want:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
for i in range (0,5):
    for epoch in range(0, num_epochs):
        x = np.append(x,epoch)
        y = np.append(y,accuracy)
        z = np.append(z, running_loss/j)
    axs[0].plot(x, y)
    axs[1].plot(x, z)
fig.suptitle('Model Evlauation')
axs[0].set_xlabel('Number of epochs')
axs[1].set_xlabel('Number of epochs')
axs[0].set_ylabel('Accuracy')
axs[1].set_ylabel('Loss')
fig.tight_layout(pad=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: No problem! I remember it took me some time before I understand the subplots and other things like that!